# how can i use async/await to call Future obj in python3.6

Tags: async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I have doubts about Python's await and hava an example,it tries to use await to fetch results from the future obj.

```
import time
import asyncio
import time
import random
import threading

db = {
    "yzh": "pig",
    "zhh": "big pig"
}
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def _get_redis(username, clb):
    def foo():    
        data = db[username]    
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("start clb")
        clb(data)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    t1.start()


def get_redis(username):
    print("start get redis")
    myfuture = asyncio.Future()
    def clb(result):
        print("clb call")
        myfuture.set_result(result)

    _get_redis(username, clb)
    return myfuture

async def main():
    print("start main")
    data = await get_redis("yzh")
    print("data is {}".format(data))

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(main()))
loop.close()
```

and i got output without future's result:

```
start main
start get redis
start clb
clb call
```

How should i use await to get the future's result?I tried many times. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got the answer.  schedule a callback from a different thread, the AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe() method should be used.(https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, you're supposed to use [loop.call_soon_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe) when running an asyncio callback from a thread:

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(myfuture.set_result, result)
```

However, a better approach for calling a synchronous function from asyncio is to use [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor):

```
def _get_redis(username):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return db[username]

async def get_redis(username):
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, _get_redis, username)
```

This way, you won't have to deal with futures and thread-safe callbacks.